# Need to update db immediately any changes in response of third party api occurs

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using third party api,just passing required parameters and getting response.In this case I need to check response in every minute and based on it doing some operations.

**For Example**:- if request status on third party updated for 1000 rows then it should update my db's 1000 rows simultaneously.

I can set cronjob for this scenerio. But I need some better solution if any changes occur in third party api response then automatically db operations will perform instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the 3rd-party service provides a way to set up a webhook (or other notification procedure) whereby it will actively send you some information when an update occurs, then you really have no other option than to poll it frequently and observe any changes.